# Signing WSDL request body Using JKS File

Tags: python, wsdl, suds, jks

I have to call a WSDL to access the services of a gateway for my application but my problem is that in order to access their services i have to sign the body of all the requests using a JKS file. My applications language is python and I'm using suds library to send my request but i can't figure out how to sign the request's body using JKS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.